# Architectual or other word meaning "at the base/foundation of" or makes up the "lower boundary of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

This might be a little confusing, but is there a word, similar to "bounded by" (which refers to all sides) or "flanked by" (which refers to left and right sides), but meaning the "lower boundary of" or "the base/foundation of"?

For example, I want to write this:

"He looked at the lobby which [blanked] the ten story building."

Where [blanked] acts like "flanked" but on the bottom/foundation of.

Of course I can say, "He looked at the lobby **which was at the base of** the ten story building." or "He looked at the lobby **at the base of** the ten story building." but that sounds wordy or inelegant.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe "anchored"?

Comment: I think it's weird because we don't know the guy's vantage point. I would use: which **ran the length** of the ten-story building.

Comment: Or maybe "footed"?

Comment: But really, "He looked at the ground floor lobby of the ten-story building"  seems much better ...

Comment: what do you guys think about "underlying"? "He looked at the lobby underlying the ten story building."--does that work/make sense?

Comment: Well, since it's a part of the building it doesn't really underlie it.  The bedrock the building is built on underlies it.